# Set up multiple intranet sites

Tags: apache2, webserver, intranet

My Ubuntu machine is on the network accessible at `\\linux-server` I have Apache2 installed and if I go to `http://linux-server` it takes me to `/var/www` as the root directory.

Is it possible on the same machine to set it up so that `http://jisaacks` points to `/var/www-jisaacks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use the NameVirtualHost directive.

There is a howto here : http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://blog.fosketts.net/2010/08/01/force-apache-redirect-canonical-hostnames-serveralias-friend/) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for Virtual host. Check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ or search for a how to article.